# how to login into a website and get redirected url contents using c#

Tags: c#, webclient, redirect

I am trying to learn a process where I can login into a website and get download all the html of the website I can do this using `webClient.DownloadString(@url);`
but the problem is that after login How can I get the redirected url. as I get the redirected url I can use this method please help me.

Comment: What do you mean 'redirected'? What's the point of downloading a website after logging in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do a fiddler trace to see if the redirection is an HTTP redirect, or is it javascript-inititated on the returned page.

Assuming it is an HTTP redirect (a 301 or a 302), you can use `HttpWebRequest`/`HttpWebResponse` to fetch the redirected location. On `HttpWebRequest`, set `AllowAutoRedirect=false`.  After the request is made, check the `HttpWebResponse` object for the `StatusCode` property. If HTTP status code is 301 or 302, check the Location header in the `Headers` property of the `HttpWebResponse`.

Comment: what if it is a javascript redirected

Comment: Usually the auth service will have a known pattern for redirecting - i.e., it will go to your known page, with some parameters that are embedded in the javascript. You can do some regex-style parsing of the returned document to figure out the URL to go to. Of course, it is fragile since the code pattern can change if auth provider changes their js code.